# What is the ConTeXt equivalent of \sloppy?

Tags: line-breaking, context, context-mkiv

Or, to phrase more precisely: How do I avoid that text goes over the right margin in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LaTeX definition of `\sloppy` is

```
\def\sloppy{%
  \tolerance 9999%
  \emergencystretch 3em%
  \hfuzz .5\p@
  \vfuzz\hfuzz}
```

That means that lines with badness of 9999 will be tolerated, interword spaces may be stretched by an additional 3em and boxes which bleed by less that 0.5pt into the margin are not even considered overfull.

Tolerance and emergencystretch can also be set in ConTeXt.  There is no high-level command to set hfuzz and vfuzz.  For a setup similar to `\sloppy` one uses

```
\setupalign[verytolerant,stretch]
```

This sets tolerance to 4500 and emergencystretch to the body font size.

Here is a short MWE:

```
\setuppapersize[A6][A6]
\setupalign[nothyphenated] % to generate overfull boxes
\starttext
\input knuth
\page
\setupalign[verytolerant,stretch]
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

---

However, I think it is better *not* to increase tolerance and emergencystretch but rather use the advanced features of [microtypography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtypography) such as margin kerning (called [hanging punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging_punctuation)) and font expansion (called [HZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hz-program)).  Before you can use these features you have to enable the corresponding font features

```
\definefontfeature
  [default][default]
  [protrusion=quality,
   expansion=quality]
```

Then you can enable both via

```
\setupalign[hz,hanging]
```

If you still get bad breaks, try rewording the sentence or try `\looseness=1` or `\looseness=-1` on the paragraph with the bad break.